# using selenium to run Firefox in headless mode error: 'Options' object has no attribute 'binary'

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-headless

I just started using selenium and wanted to check the status of a ps5 at Walmart
but I get the error 'Options' object has no attribute 'binary'
it worked fine before I tried to run it in headless mode.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.walmart.com/ip/Sony-PlayStation-5-Video-Game-Console/994712501')

print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='prod-blitz-copy-message']").text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Firefox

Instead of this

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

import it as

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=option)
```